# Node.js use variable from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have **app.js**

```
var List = {};
var Entity = require('./entity.js');
var main = new Entity(); // should be changed List
console.log(List) // still empty
```

and **entity.js**

```
class Entity {
  constructor(){
    this.id = Math.random();
    List[this.id] = this; // List == undefined
  }
}
module.exports = Entity;
```

How can I use List as global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import `List` in `entity.js`:

At the end of app.js:

```
module.exports = List;
```

At the start of entity.js:

```
const List = require('./app.js');
```

If your `app.js` needs to export something else as well, then export an object with a `List` property instead:

At the end of app.js:

```
module.exports.List = List;
```

At the start of entity.js:

```
const List = require('./app.js').List;
```

You could also consider putting `List` into its own module that both `app.js` and `entity.js` import.

*Don't* make List a global variable, if at all possible - work *with* the module system instead, explicit dependencies without global pollution is one of a module system's big advantages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass List param and access in constructor ...

```
new Entity(List);

constructor(List){
 ...
```